First derivative of $f(A) = \frac{1}{\lambda_{\min}(A)}$ for perturbed matrix
I am working with the matrix function
$$
f(A) = \frac{1}{\lambda_{\min}(A)},
$$ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a positive definite matrix and $\lambda_{\min}(A)$ is its smallest eigenvalue. I am interested in computing the first derivative of this function when $A$ is perturbed by a matrix $B$, i.e., I want to find the first-order derivative in the Taylor expansion of $f(A + \epsilon B)$.
More concretely, the first-order Taylor expansion of $f$ around $A$ is given by:
$$
f(A + \epsilon B) = f(A) + \epsilon \cdot Df(A)[B] + R_1(A, B, \epsilon),
$$
where $Df(A)[B]$ is the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of $B$.
My question is: How do I compute $Df(A)[B]$ explicitly?
I suspect this involves the perturbation of the eigenvalue $\lambda_{\min}(A)$, but I'm unsure about the exact steps or formula. Any help or references on computing this directional derivative would be greatly appreciated!

First order perturbation theory gives you
$$\frac{1}{\lambda_{\rm min}(A+\epsilon B)}=\frac{1}{\lambda_{\rm min}(A)}-\frac{\epsilon}{\lambda_{\rm min}(A)^2}\langle v_0|B|v_0\rangle+{\cal O}(\epsilon^2),$$
where $v_0$ is the (normalized) eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda_{\rm min}(A)$. It is assumed here that this eigenvalue is non-degenerate (multiplicity one).
If the eigenvalue $\lambda_{\rm min}(A)$ is degenerate, multiplicity $m$, there is a set of orthonormal eigenvectors $v_1,v_2,\ldots v_m$. Then you need to first diagonalize the $m\times m$ matrix $C$ with elements $C_{ij}=\langle v_i|B|v_j\rangle$. Denote the ordered eigenvalues of $C$ by $c_1\leq c_2\leq \ldots \leq c_m$. The first order perturbation of the minimal eigenvalue of $A+\epsilon B$ is given by
$$\frac{1}{\lambda_{\rm min}(A+\epsilon B)}=\frac{1}{\lambda_{\rm min}(A)}-\frac{\epsilon c_1}{\lambda_{\rm min}(A)^2}+{\cal O}(\epsilon^2).$$

A follow-up question: Is there a way to bound the $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$ term in this expansion? Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

you can just calculate the $O(\epsilon^2)$ term; scroll down to "Second-order and higher-order corrections" on the perturbation theory page I linked to.

Thank you. I am new to Bra–ket notation, so I might be missing something:  shouldn't $\langle u_{i_0} | B | u_{i_0} \rangle$ in the first-order perturbation be replaced by $\langle u_{i_0} | C | u_{i_0} \rangle$? Otherwise, it seems that the dimensions do not work.

right, I have rephrased it so that this dimension mismatch is avoided.

Thank you, I really appreciate it. I am able to show the results for the non-degenerate case using the spectral function. Do you have any hints for showing the results for the degenerate case? Specifically, why do we first project the matrix $B$ into the subspace spanned by $v_1$ to $v_m$, and then choose the minimum eigenvalue?

the degenerate eigenvalues are split by the perturbation, by an amount $\epsilon c_i$, as explained in the Wiki page I linked to; so you have a set of perturbed eigenvalues $\mu_i$ given by $1/\mu_i=1/\lambda_{\rm min}-\epsilon c_i/\lambda_{\rm min}^2$; the smallest $\mu_i$ corresponds to the smallest $c_i$ (assuming $\epsilon>0$).

Thanks. I believe my confusion arises from the fact that, according to the theory of spectral functions in \href{https://carmamaths.org/resources/jon/Preprints/Books/CaNo2/cano2f.pdf} (see specifically Corollary 5.2.5 and Equation 5.2.6), it seems that $c_1$ in the first-order perturbation should be computed as $\sum_{i = 1}^{m} \langle v_i | B | v_i \rangle$.

$\sum_{i=1}^m \langle v_i|B|v_i\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^m c_i$; that is the sum of the displacements of the $m$ eigenvalues; but you seek only the displacement of the smallest eigenvalue, which is $c_1$.

Thank you. So, technically, there is no need to project all of $B$ onto the subspace spanned by $v_1$ to $v_m$. Instead, we can obtain $c_1$ in the first-order perturbation you mentioned by taking the minimum of $\langle v_i | B | v_i \rangle$ for $i = 1, \dots, m$, correct?

no, that is not correct; the $v_i$'s are not uniquely defined, you can choose any basis in the degenerate subspace; the correct basis vectors for the perturbation theory are those for which $\langle u_i|B|u_j\rangle=0$ for $i\neq j$.
